# Okular 20.12.3 does not open pdf after compilation in LyX

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, okular

After updating okular from version 1.3.3 to okular 20.12.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 it can can't open pdf after it's compiled in LyX 2.3.6.1 (after clicking View button). Error message: "`Could not open file:///var/lib/snapd/void/sample.pdf`" (sample.lyx is the source file). Directory '`/var/lib/snapd/void`' really exists. Probably it has to do with insufficient permissions of okular (I can open pdf files in my home folder)? It was installed using Ubuntu Software GUI (I guess with snap which installs programs with minimal permissions). I tried apt install, but it installs only okular 1.3.3. Installing latest version of okular with apt may probably be a solution or installing it's deb file directly (didn't find it).

Older version of okular 1.3.3 and evince open compiled pdf-s without any problems.

Comment: Sure that `sample.ppf` exits in that route and it is the ouput of the lyx file and not an image? Where is `sample.lyx? ` Why the hell is searching the supposed output under /var/...  instead from you home directory or /tmp  where the document is really compiled?

Comment: @Fran Snap runs all applications in separate containers, this complicates matters a lot.

Comment: Lately I'm not aware of what's new in Ubuntu, but LyX has been always available trough apt. It will no use another installation procedures if there a  .deb packages in official repositories or in the LyX site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared because of permission restrictions of okular, installed through snap. After changing the temporary directory of Lyx (Menu [Tools]->[Preferences]->[Paths]) from `/tmp` to `/home/...` everything works.