# Backward search not working in LyX with Okular

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, forward-inverse-search, okular

Backward search not working in lyx 2.3.6 and okular 22.08.2 (in Ubuntu 22.04).
I've implemented steps from https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX: [Settings]->[Configure Okular]->[Editor] has `LyX Client` with command `lyxclient -g %f %l`. In browse mode I shift+left-click on a position with no effect in LyX. Forward search works fine. Could anyone recommend something to enable the backward search?

P.S. Following [inability of okular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653443/okular-20-12-3-does-not-open-pdf-after-compilation-in-lyx) to open in `/tmp` dir I specified my own custom LyX temp directory in [Preferences]->[Paths]. I think this is the cause of problem, because in terminal "lyxclient -g /home/user/Desktop/somefile.lyx 3" reports "No suitable server found". In contrast "lyxclient -t [path to lyx_temp_dir] -g /home/user/Desktop/somefile.lyx 3" pops up an error in opened LyX "Invalid position requested by inverse search".

Comment: Did you check the Enable Forward/Reverse button in LyX's GUI?

Comment: Could you specify where this button is located? I didn't see it.

Comment: fifth button from the left of the View button (at least with the standard toolbar). The order from the view button (the one with the eyes icon) should be View, Update, View master, Update master, then Enable Forward/Reverse search

Comment: Thanks.Actually it was disabled.Enabling it however didn't help to solve my problem. I tried to set "\\.\pipe\lyxpipe" for LyxServerPipe in [Preferences]->[Directories], and replaced [Converter] (in Latex(pdfLatex)->pdf(pdflatex) in [Preferences]->[File handling]->[Converters]) from 'pdflatex $$i' to 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 $$i' following https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473572/lyx-2-3-how-can-i-successfully-set-up-the-forward-and-inverse-search but with no success.It would be nice to know the working values for [Converter] and command in okular linking back to lyx

Comment: actually "\\.\pipe\lyxpipe" is relevant only for windows, if you are using Unix it should be "~/.lyx/lyxpipe" or maybe "~/.lyxpipe". I think what you did with the convertor is correct, after doing that pdflatex should generate .synctex.gz files, after clicking on the View button, you can open the temp directory where LyX compiles the .tex file via Document->Latex Log->Open Containing Directory or   View->Latex Log->Open Containing Directory and check that these files are generated.

Comment: Maybe it would be to reconfigure LyX via `Tools->Reconfigure` and reset LyX after changing the pipe

Comment: I believe it has something to do with custom LyX temp directory. I've specified a custom one, as otherwise okular was not able to open the document, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653443/okular-20-12-3-does-not-open-pdf-after-compilation-in-lyx. In terminal "lyxclient -g /home/user/Desktop/somefile.lyx 3" reports "No suitable server found". In contrast "lyxclient -t <path to lyx_temp_dir> -g /home/user/Desktop/somefile.lyx 3" pops up an error in opened LyX "Invalid position requested by inverse search". Conf in okular "lyxclient -t <path to lyx_temp_dir> -g %f %l" has no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last comment. I never changed my Temp directory, so I don't if it is related, and if so how to solve it. If you won't find an answer here, you should try LyX's users list: http://lists.lyx.org/mailman/listinfo/lyx-users